# WakeOnLan криво работает

Tags: linux

Значит настроил я WOL. И появились проблема
Проблемы:

1. После подключение ПК в розетку он не хочет запускаться через WOL пока его 1 раз не включишь
2. Перестаёт работать WOL после 20 минут из внешнего мира, в локальной сети всё работает всегда.

Comment: Поставил линукс, так как wol нету. А мало чего то там, что бы создать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. WOL активируется во время загрузки и не сохраняется нигде. Возможно стоит поменять батарейку RTC (но это не точно). Чтоб обойти это включите в CMOS включение компьютера при восстановлении питания. Компьютер включится и вы его можете выключить если он на данный момент не нужен удаленно, а потом включить по wol.
2. Через некоторое время в роутере пропадает arp запись на ip адрес. Для проброса порта используйте бродкаст адрес (192.168.0.255)

Comment: 1. Спасибо 2. Не работает броадкаст. Я сделал так:  запустил телнет и сделал arp запись, но она работает только до перезагрузки роутера. Надо сделать что бы при включении выполнялась та команда

Comment: Попробуй 255.255.255.255

Comment: Всё равно не хочет вообще даже сразу после выключения. Работает если только IP указывать того ПК и    закинуть запись в ARP